# Unknown green colour rendering in eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image][image]
I get this annoying green colour and can't figure out why is this happening I tried most of thing's but still couldn't figure out a way to fix it.

Comment: I would suspect that this is caused by the subsurface scattering of the skin.

Comment: Yes your correct. Is there any solution for this